# What does *substantive* in the term 'substantive normative claim' mean?

Tags: terminology, metaethics, definitions

In Sharon Street's paper, "[Nothing "Really" Matters, but That's Not What Matters](https://files.nyu.edu/ss194/public/sharonstreet/Writing_files/Paper%2011%20for%20website%20-%20Nothing%20'Really'%20Matters,%20but%20That's%20Not%20What%20Matters.pdf)", she uses the phrase *substantive normative-claim*:

> I take it
>   that this is because Parfit is thinking of the claim in question—about our reason to take the
>   medicine—as a substantive normative claim, and so more “metaethical” kinds of worries do not
>   spring to mind as potentially relevant here....

I don't know what she uses *substantive* to express.

I had hoped that the dictionary definitions of the adjective would help me. However, the dictionaries include more than one meta-ethically relevant definition of *substantive*.

> **sub·stan·tive**
>
> 1. having a firm basis in reality and therefore important, meaningful, or considerable.
>      "there is no substantive evidence for the efficacy of these drugs"
> 2. having a separate independent existence
> 3. defining rights and duties as opposed to giving the rules by which such things are established.

What does *substantive* in the phrase 'substantive normative claim' mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a paragraph in Parfit's [*On What Matters*](https://books.google.at/books?id=mTpLAAAAQBAJ) that gives a definition of "substantive normative claim":

> There is another way in which some people have come to accept
>   subjective theories about reasons. We can call some normative claim
>   substantive when this claim both
>
> (a) states that something has some normative property,
>   and
>
> (b) is significant, by being a claim with which we might disagree,
>   or which might be informative, by telling us something that
>   we didn’t already know. 
>   (p. 70)

Comment: Substantive *includes* being non-tautological but is not fully defined by that.

Comment: A concise answer, and to the point. You can and should [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)!